# Get nodes in leaf host group

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to get all then nodes under a host group in order to     fill a cluster variable in a template. My ansible hosts is something like this

```
[des_cns]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

[des_rtc]
10.0.0.11
10.0.0.12

[des_ogl]
10.0.0.21
10.0.0.22

[des:children]
des_cns
des_rtc
des_ogl

[clustered:children]
des
```

When launching my playbook for 10.0.0.1, I can get with groups['des_cns'] all the nodes in this group (this is what i want) but seems like I'm unable to do so with variables. Whith group_names i get all groups in which this IP matches, but i only want the leaf group. I have managed to use a _ in all leaf groups for filtering purposes.

The closer i can get is (im sure im messing too much with this line):

```
{{groups[group_names|list|join(' ')|regex_findall('[a-z]*_[a_z]*')|to_json]}}
```

But that returns an error saying dict object has no attribute '[\"des_cns\"]'...

Thank you all for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` filter and `search` test:

```
{{ groups[ group_names | select('search','_') | first ] }}
```

Inner expression: selects only groups with `_` character from `group_names` and take only first item out of it.